# How would I add an object I created to an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

There is a class called `Post`, which represents a post someone would make on a social media website. I want to be able to add a post to an arraylist so that later on I can prompt the user to make a post and then return the previous posts.

Here is the PostManager class

```
public class PostManager {

    private ArrayList<Post> postList;

    public PostManager() {
        this.postList = new ArrayList<Post>();
    }

    public void addPost() {
        this.postList.add(Post(String))
    }



}
```

And here is the Post class

```
public class Post {
    private String username;
    private long timestamp;
    private int likes;
    private ArrayList<String> comments;

    public Post(String author) {
        this.username = author;
        this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.likes = 0;
        this.comments = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void like() {
        this.likes++;
    }
    public void unlike() {
        if (this.likes > 0) {
            this.likes--;
        }
    }
    public void addComment(String text) {
        this.comments.add(text);
    }
    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return this.timestamp;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println(this.username);
        System.out.print(timeString(this.timestamp));

        if (this.likes > 0) {
            System.out.println("  -  " + this.likes + " people like this.");
        } else {
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (this.comments.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("   No comments.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("   " + this.comments.size() + " comment(s). Click here to view.");
        }
    }

    private String timeString(long time) {
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long pastMillis = current - time;      // time passed in milliseconds
        long seconds = pastMillis / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;
        if (minutes > 0) {
            return minutes + " minutes ago";
        } else {
            return seconds + " seconds ago";
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = this.username + "\n";
        result += this.timeString(this.timestamp) + "\n";

        if (this.likes > 0) {
            result += "  -  " + this.likes + " people like this.\n";
        } else {
            result += "\n";
        }

        if (this.comments.isEmpty()) {
            result += "No comments.\n";
        } else {
            result += this.comments.size() + " comment(s). Click here to view.\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I need to know how would I be able to add the Post to the arraylist

Comment: Create an instance of Post and add it to the ArrayList. Which part of that is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you want to do something like the following:

```
public class PostManager {

    private ArrayList<Post> postList;

    public PostManager() {
        this.postList = new ArrayList<Post>();
    }

    public void addPost(Post newPost) {
        this.postList.add(newPost);
    }

    public ArrayList<Post> getPosts(){
        return this.postList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```java
public void addPost(Post somePost) {
    this.postList.add(somePost)
}
```

Comment: This is an answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `Post` class a Java bean. For this create a default constructor and public getters/setters for the fields.

```
public class Post {

    public Post(){this(null);}

    public Post(String author) {
        this.username = author;
        this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.likes = 0;
        this.comments = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    private String username;

    public void setUsername(String username){
      this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
      return username;
    }
   ....
}
```

Now you can create a `Post` instance in any time and initialize `username` with `author` or whatever value is available to you. You can create getters/setters for other fields, so you'll be able to modify the state of the bean with actual values.

In `PostManager` you can implement a singleton pattern and make a static methods to manipulate posts

```
public class PostManager {

    private List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<Post>();

    private static PostManager instance = new PostManager();

    private PostManager (){}

    public static PostManager getInstance(){
      return instance;
    }

    public List<Post> getPostList(){
      return postList;
    }

    public static void addPost() {
        PostManager.getInstance().add(new Post());
    }

    public static Post getPostByUsername(String author) {
        for (Post p: PostManager.getInstance().getPostList())
            if ((p.getUsername() == null && author == null) ||
                (p.getUsername() != null && p.getUsername().equals(author)))
              return p;
        return null;
    }       
}
```

assumed that `username` is a unique field or you better add `id` field to identify `Post`s in the list if you don't want to retrieve them by index.

Answer (score -1):

Your `PostManager` Class already has an `addPost` Method which "adds" a post to your `private ArrayList`.

Your question doesn't seem to make sense in this context, so I am going to assume you mean "How do I add a post to my PostManager?". Even then I'm not sure how you wouldn't know how to do that if you wrote the above code... but I will give you an example of how in the offchance that is what you meant.

```
private PostManager pm;

void main()
{
    pm = new PostManager();

    string author = "John";
    Post p = new Post(author);
    md.addPost(p);

    pm.addPost(new Post("Jane"));
}
```

**EDIT**: I just noticed that your addPost() Method was implemented incorrectly which is why you couldn't add posts. That was my bad, as I read the code, I just assumed it actually did what it said it did.